# Why are two TextView located the center of LinearLayout when I use constraint in Android Studio 3.1.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I hope to design UI, the top of UI is AD, the buttom of UI is a Close button, and the LinearLayout named myLinearLayout will fill in the other space.
So I write the following code, and then I add two TextView controls tvDetail and tvName into myLinearLayout.

I don't add any constraint for the two TextView controls, I think the two TextView controls will be located the left and top of myLinearLayout.

But in fact they are located the center of myLinearLayout (Please see image), why ?

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnClose"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Details"
         />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            />


    </LinearLayout>




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/BtnClose"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: that's because your container layout that is "Linear Layout" does have constraints that's why it's in the middle. those tv are in that layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` has `wrap_content` width and height.
Set them to `0dp`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
...>
```

0dp is equivalent to "MATCH_CONSTRAINT". See [ConstraintLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints).

Comment: Thanks! your code OK, but  why do I need to set android:layout_width="0dp" and 
    android:layout_height="0dp" ?

Comment: 0dp is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT". When a dimension is set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space. Seen at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have the following on your `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This 'shrinks' the LinearLayout to only be as wide and high as the contents it contains.

Change your `layout_width` and `layout_height` as follow:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Or alternatively, give the give the `layout_height` and `layout_width` a certain size.